# Grouping ng-repeat Items into sets to populate table with set number of records per row

Tags: angularjs

I am converting MVC to AngularJS. I have a model passed to the View and I take the model and used LINQ to group into set of 4 items. 
So, if I have 12 records, I will get 3 sets of 4 records. Reason. I am insert 4 records per row in a table. Here is the MVC code

```
@foreach (var productGroup in ((Model.Select((e, i) => new { Product = e, Grouping = (i / 4) }).GroupBy(e => e.Grouping))
{
    <tr>
        @foreach (var product in productGroup)
        {
            <td>
                <div><br /></div>
                <img src=@product.Product.Thumbnail style="width: 200px; height: 200px" />
                <div><br /></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p><strong>@product.Product.DescriptionLine1<br></strong></p>
                    <p><small>@product.Product.DescriptionLine2<br></small></p>
                </div>
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

So far in AngularJS, I converted the code to

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in listItems">
                    <td>
                        <img ng-src="{{item.thumbnail}}" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"/>
                        <div><br/>
                        </div>
                        <div small>
                            <span ng-bind="item.descriptionLine1"></span><br/>
                            <span ng-bind="item.descriptionLine2"></span><br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

How do I use LINQ to group into sets of 4 for listItems? If I can't use LINQ, how else can I perform the grouping? Thanks.

Comment: CSS? What if each of your item is 25% of the width it can use?

Comment: `<table>` is a poor layout element for doing this ... especially if you want this to be responsive

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example which displays 4 records per row.However please note there can be also better approach and am sure experts would enlighten that.

I have assumed you have `$scope.items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f','g','k','k','l','k'];` for simplicity as I don't know the real structure.You can modify accordingly.

Now you can use angular `$index` to limit 4 records each row like this.This way you break on 4th record each time on loop.

```
<div ng-repeat="_ in items">
        <span ng-show="($parent.$index % 4 == 0) && ($parent.$index + 4 > $index) && ($parent.$index <= $index)" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <span ng-show="1">
                {{item}}
            </span>
        </span>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LjX3m/5/) example on same.